# how can I do so that in the cycle for to not find a data do not stop me and continue the process

Tags: python

The problem is that when you start running the cycle for not being stopped by not finding in this case Authors or DOI, I want you to continue with the process and finish the cycle.

I tried with conditional`(if, else)`, the function `pass`, `continue`, but it did not work

```
for Container in Articulos:
    #Container.find("a",{"class":"author"})
    TitleID=Container.strong["id"]
    Title=Container.strong.text.strip()
    date=Container.find_all("span",{"style":"margin: 0"})
    #date[0].text.strip()
    Year=date[1].text.strip()
    DOI=Container.find("span",{"class":"DOIResults"}).text.split()
    if len (DOI) == 0:
        DOI=["","No hay DOI"]
        pass
    Journal=Container.find_all("",{"class":"showTooltip dropdown-toggle"})
    Journal2=Journal[2].text.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try, except. Don’t make it vague though. Specify your excepts.

Comment: Please fully explain your answer. Some example code would assist the question asker.